# Im trying to make a simple blog post, and the fields in the .erb file are not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the server set up on ruby on rails. The sites work fine, apart from the posts/new.erb the fields i have used to include a Title input and a text area input for the content do not appear when loading the site. I am using bulma-rails and simple forms.

```html
<h1 class="title">New Post</h1>


<div class="section">
  <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <% f.input :title , input_html: { class: 'input'},  wrapper: false, label_html: { class: ' label'} %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <% f.input :content , input_html: { class: 'textarea'},  wrapper: false, label_html: { class: ' label'} %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% f.button :submit, 'Create new post', class: "button is-primary" %>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

The expected result of loading this page would be that there would be two inputs, and a button. The page only loads the header.

Comment: Note the difference in your erb syntax between your form, which likely renders (view source), and your form elements (which don't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not displaying your inputs and your button, change this:

```
<% f.input :title %>
```

to this:

```
<%= f.input :title %>
```

In the first block you're only executing ruby, to display the output you should use an `=`.